# FCM Push - Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: firebase, curl, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, unauthorized

I am trying to send fcm message to specific topic by using cURL command but it says error like

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 401,
> "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
> "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
> }
> }

[image]

I used server key from firebase console

[image]

I followed this [FCM Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)

How to resolve this 401 error.

Comment: I have the same error, did you find anything since then ?

Comment: answered here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318682/request-had-invalid-authentication-credentials-when-using-curl-to-call-firebas

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think why, this is because you need a Service account that will handle it for you.

So follow the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server.) and this will make you generate a new key pair.  With this key, you can get the access token from a code (see in python below but the documentation has support for NodeJS / Java) :

```
def _get_access_token():
  """Retrieve a valid access token that can be used to authorize requests.

  :return: Access token.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      'service-account.json', SCOPES)
  access_token_info = credentials.get_access_token()
  return access_token_info.access_tokenmessaging.py
```

And you just have to print this value, copy-paste it and use it as the `Bearer` OAuth 2 access token.