# "Request had invalid authentication credentials" when using cURL to call Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to trigger my Android app to receive a simple push message. I want to use `cURL`. I tried to follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest)  but I'm getting a 401... This used to work, did anything change?

- My Server key: AAAArxt...CelsCl
- My firebase project URL: my-project...485 (taken from the URL, or the "Project ID", found under "General")
- My device token: fNBu...eHCAgI

[image]

**I retrieved my device token using this code:**

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { token: String ->
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        Log.d("TAG", "retrieve token successful : $token")
    } else {
        Log.w("TAG", "token should not be null...")
    }
}.addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? -> }.addOnCanceledListener {}
.addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String> ->
    Log.v("TAG", "This is the token : " + task.result)
}
```

**My cURL Code:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer AAAArxt...CelsCl" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"message":{
   "notification":{
     "title":"FCM Message",
     "body":"This is an FCM Message"
   },
   "token":"fNBu...eHCAgI"
}}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project...485/messages:send
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

**Created the OAuth 2.0 token, copied the `access_token` starting with `ya29.`:**

[image]

Got back a 403 error. It refers to `project-752077406211`. This is unknown to me. I don't see an option to create / add an existing project?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/project-7520...211' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "resource": "projects/project-7520...211",
          "permission": "cloudmessaging.messages.create"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the token in your authorization header is wrong. That's not something we can help you with.

Comment: Hi Doug, I double-checked and added more details to my question. the credentials are correct I think. The "Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)" is new. This wasn't there before and before it worked like this. Am I supposed to do something with the service account? The documentation doesn't refer to this (yet?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using FCM HTTP v1 API, the Authorization Bearer in the request should be OAuth 2.0 access token instead of the Server Key.

Below are the options you can try to generate an OAuth 2.0 access token:

A) Using [Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

1. Select and Authorize Firebase Cloud Messaging API v1
2. Select https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging as the scope
3. Click Authorize APIs
4. Once Authorization code is generated, exchange it to access token
5. Copy the access token and use it in the request

B) Using [Firebase Cloud Messaging Node.js Quickstart Project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/messaging)

1. [Install Firebase Admin SDK and Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)
2. Download the quickstart project and follow the guide in README.md file
3. Update index.js and log the access token
4. Copy the access token and use it in the request

Note that the usual prefix of access token is `ya29.`

> `Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA`

Lastly, you may also want to visit this [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) from FCM Legacy HTTP API to FCM HTTP v1 API.

Comment: Did the steps from A, got a 403 now. What did I miss?

Comment: Did you select an account which has access to the Firebase project that you'e using in the request? Check the project id in the FCM HTTP v1 request URL and try to open the Firebase console to see if you have access to it

Comment: ofcourse, it works now. thanks for your quick and complete response!